# How would I be able to acquire data using a picture?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning

I need to find a way to acquire data from a picture for a new project I am trying to do. This involves tracking eye movements.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out OpenCV? If that's not an option, consider any number of the image libraries available in Python -- just about all of them have a number of encoding representations, such as RGBA, HSV, Bayer, and LVU. Note that the four encodings that I've mentioned has different channels are are uncompressed, which would give you the full data from each frame you're analyzing.